# Export to GCal from GSheet using Apps Script: Exception: Invalid argument: title

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, calendar

I got an error when try to create an event from GSheet data to GCal using Apps script:  *Exception: Invalid argument: title*

The code i used:

```
function scheduleEvents() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("____");

  var workplans = spreadsheet.getRange("GE!F14:G16").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<workplans.length; x++) {
    var event = workplans[x];

    var startTime = new Date(event[0]);
    var endTime = new Date(event[1]);
    var tasks = event[2];

    eventCal.createEvent(tasks, startTime, endTime);

  }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `tasks` is `undefined`: range `GE!F14:G16` has only two columns and `tasks` is sourced from the third column `event[2]`.